# Limit of sec⁻¹ function

Tags: calculus, limits

I thought of two approaches to this problem ,

**1st -**

[image: 1st method]

**2nd -**

[image: 2nd method]

When I plot the graph of this function I get a curve which is not defined for any positive values , therefore my answer should be that the limit does not exist but then I cannot find out the mistake in my first approach to the problem.

[image: graph]

Comment: Please do not rely on pictures of text. [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: $x\to\infty$ is equivalent to $1/x\to0^+$, not $1/x\to0$; to compute $\mbox{arcsec}\frac{1}{1+1/x}$ (i.e. $\arccos(1+1/x)$), you need $1/x\to0^-$.

Comment: The problem is you are bringing the limit inside of the $\mathrm{arcsec}$. You cannot do this because $\mathrm{arcsec}(x)$ is not continuous at $x=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{t}{1+t}=1$. It is only true in general that $$\lim_{x\to a}f(g(x)) = f\left(\lim_{x\to a} g(x)\right)$$ if $f$ is continuous and the limit of $g$ exists at the point in question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think that

$$\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$$

doesn't exist "because the input $2$ is not in the domain of the function"?

EDIT:  It is not the case that

$$\frac{x^2-4}{x-2} = x+2,$$

because the two functions have different domains. It is the case that

$$\frac{x^2-4}{x-2} = x+2, \; x\neq 2.$$

Limits were invented just for cases like this.

Comment: because this can be simplified to just ( x+2 ), the limit exists and is equal to 4 in this case.

Comment: See edits above